# Словарь в html таблицу python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

Мне надо из словарь значений получить html таблицу. Взгляд упал на `jinja`. Начал писать код, в итоге не знаю как получить то что я хочу.
У меня есть

```
array1 = [
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 37), 'Саша'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 28, 16, 2), 'Олег'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 40), 'Саша'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 41), 'Саша'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Костя'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Костя'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Олег'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Саша']
]

result = {}
for date, name in array1:
    if date.date() not in result:
        result[date.date()] = {}
    result[date.date()][name] = result[date.date()].get(name, 0) + 1

template = jinja2.Template("""\
<table class="table-2">
  <tr>
    <td>Отчет</td>
  {% for x in rows_1 %}
    <td>{{ x }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  
  {% for y in name %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ y }}</td>

    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  
</table>
""")


v_k = [v for k, v in result.items()]
all_name = []
for el in v_k:
    for k, v in el.items():
        all_name.append(k) 

unique_name = list(set(all_name))

html_tab = template.render(
rows_1=[k for k, v in result.items()],
name = unique_name,
)

print(html_tab)
```

В итоге я получаю такую html таблицу.

```html
<table class="table-2">
  <tr>
    <td>Отчет</td>

    <td>2020-10-27</td>

    <td>2020-10-28</td>

  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Костя</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Саша</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Олег</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Не понимаю как теперь по каждой дате вставить в эту таблицу количество вхождений 1 человека.
чтобы получить

```
Отчет   2020-10-27  2020-10-28
Костя   2
Саша    4
Олег    1           1
```

Может я изначально выбрал неправильный подход и методы. Подскажите пожалуйста как такое лучше всего реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import datetime
import jinja2

array1 = [
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 37), 'Саша'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 28, 16, 2), 'Олег'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 40), 'Саша'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 41), 'Саша'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Костя'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Костя'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Олег'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Саша']
]

result = dict()
for dt, name in array1:
    date = dt.date()
    if date not in result:
        result[date] = dict()
    result[date][name] = result[date].get(name, 0) + 1

name_by_results = dict()
for i, (date, name_by_number) in enumerate(result.items()):
    for name, number in name_by_number.items():
        if name not in name_by_results:
            name_by_results[name] = [""] * len(result)

        name_by_results[name][i] = number


template = jinja2.Template("""\
<table class="table-2">
  <tr>
    <td>Отчет</td>
  {% for x in header %}
    <td>{{ x }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>

  {% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
        {% for x in row %}        
        <td>{{ x }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</table>
""")

unique_name = sorted(name_by_results)
rows = []
for name in unique_name:
    rows.append([name] + name_by_results[name])

html_tab = template.render(
    header=result.keys(),
    rows=rows,
)
print(html_tab)
```

---

Вариант 2, немного усложнил шаблон `jinja`, но упростил подготовку данных:

```
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

import jinja2


array1 = [
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 37), 'Саша'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 28, 16, 2), 'Олег'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 40), 'Саша'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 41), 'Саша'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Костя'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Костя'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Олег'],
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Саша']
]

result = defaultdict(dict)
dates = set()

for dt, name in array1:
    date = dt.date()

    if name not in result:
        result[name] = dict()

    if date not in result[name]:
        result[name][date] = 0

    result[name][date] += 1
    dates.add(date)

template = jinja2.Template("""\
<table class="table-2">
  <tr>
    <td>Отчет</td>
  {% for date in dates %}
    <td>{{ date }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% for name, date_by_number in result.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
      {% for date in dates %}
        <td>{{ date_by_number.get(date, "") }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
""")

html_tab = template.render(
    dates=sorted(dates),
    result=result,
)
print(html_tab)
```

Тут в `result` будет словарь, где ключом будет имя, а значением словарь, в котором ключом будет дата, а значением счетчик, пример:

```
{
    'Саша':  {datetime.date(2020, 10, 27): 4}, 
    'Олег':  {datetime.date(2020, 10, 28): 1, datetime.date(2020, 10, 27): 1}, 
    'Костя': {datetime.date(2020, 10, 27): 2}
}
```

Comment: все отлично работает! Спасибо!

Comment: Очень смущает вот эта конструкция `result[date][name] = result[date].get(name, 0) + 1` - зачем это делать вручную, если для того, что бы этого не делать, есть куча других способов? Ну и инициализация пустого словаря через `dict()` - это моветон для питона

Comment: @cauf, поленился переписывать, оставив алгоритм автора вопроса

Comment: @cauf, ... конечно, там можно использовать `Counter`, но для начала нужно будет пройтись по всему `array1`, составив словарь, где ключом будет дата, а значением список имен, чтобы после к этому списку применить `Counter`. Или можно отрефакторить `result[date][name] = result[date].get(name, 0) + 1` до `result[date][name] += 1`, если строкой выше использовать `defaultdict`: `result[date] = defaultdict(int)`. Но мне кажется, профита не так много от этих действий

Comment: @Вадим, критика и ответ cauf помогли переосмыслить алгоритм, сделал второй вариант, посмотрите его :)

Comment: @cauf, спасибо за критику, добавил вариант 2 :)

Comment: 2 вариант красивый и сильно сокращает код)

Comment: кстати пришлось добавить `sort_date = sorted(list(dates))` и пихать его в jinja чтобы даты сортировались

Comment: @Вадим, понятно... обновил ответ и кст, можно проще: `dates=sorted(dates),`

Answer (score 3):

Мой вариант такой:

```py
import datetime
from collections import Counter
import jinja2

array1 = [
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 37), 'Саша'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 28, 16, 2), 'Олег'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 40), 'Саша'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 16, 41), 'Саша'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Костя'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Костя'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 27), 'Олег'], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 12, 54), 'Саша']
]

names = [i[1] for i in array1 ]
all_data = {}
dates = list(set([ i[0].strftime("%d.%m.%Y") for i in array1 ]))

for i in array1:
    date:datetime.datetime = i[0]
    name:str = i[1]
    if name not in all_data.keys():
        all_data[name] = []
    all_data[name].append(date.date().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

res = {nm: Counter(dts) for nm, dts in all_data.items()}

template = jinja2.Template("""
    <table class="table-2">
        <tr>
            <th>Имена</th>
            {% for dt in dates %}
                <th>{{dt}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% for name in res.keys() %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                {% for dt in dates %}
                    <td>{{res[name][dt]}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
""")

print(template.render(
    res = res,
    dates = dates,
))
```

Comment: У вас хороший вариант (использование в шаблоне `dates` вместе с `res` мне нравится больше, чем то, что у меня получилось), но минус мне, считаю, не заслуженно ;)

Comment: Кст, конструкцию `dates = list(set([ ... ]))` можно упростить используя литерал множества `dates = list({ ... })`